# Insert into from multiple table with specific naming convention

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to simplify a process I run to update one table. I want to be able to insert into one table from all tables ending in "_ASO" and table created after a certain date. Currently, I have the following code which is very manual and often a lot of human error:

```
INSERT INTO [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_main_AS0]
SELECT * FROM [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_table3645_AS0]

INSERT INTO [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_main_AS0]
SELECT * FROM [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_table3587_AS0]

INSERT INTO [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_main_AS0]
SELECT * FROM [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_table5421_AS0]

INSERT INTO [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_main_AS0]
SELECT * FROM [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_table69857_AS0]
```

Is there a way to complete the same procedure 1) for all tables ending in"_AS0" and 2) "_AS0" table created after a certain date?

Answer (score 0):

This can be made to handle other databases and schemas, but should give the general idea. It might use features from SQL 2008.

```
Use DSQL

declare 
    @table sysname,
    @sql nvarchar(max),
    @startdate datetime = dateadd(Day, -14, getdate())

declare table_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
select
    name
from
    sys.tables
where
    is_ms_shipped = 0 and
    right(name, 4) = '_AS0' and
    name != 'I3_main_AS0' and -- assume we don't want to insert this into itself
    create_date >= @startDate and
    schema_id = schema_id('dbo') --simplifies things

open table_cursor

fetch next from table_cursor into @table

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
    Set @sql = N'insert into [DSQL].[dbo].[I3_main_AS0] Select * From [DSQL].[dbo].' + quotename(@table)
    Exec sp_executesql @sql
    fetch next from table_cursor into @table
end
close table_cursor
deallocate table_cursor
```